# How to compare $ n^{\epsilon} $ and $ \log^bn $ ($\epsilon>0 ,b>1)$

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics

How to compare :

1)   $ n^{\epsilon} $  and $ \log^bn $ ($\epsilon>0 ,b>1)$

and 2)$n^{\log n\log\log n}$ and   $(\log n)!$

Comment: Because you've tagged this algorithms, are you talking about asymptotic comparisons, or comparisons over the entire real line?

Comment: No, you don't @misi10...or, in fact, you've already determined the cases: $\,\epsilon >0\,,\,b>1\,$...what else?

Comment: And besides: what do you mean by $\,(\log n)!\,$? Perhaps you meant $\,\log(n!)\,$? How do you evaluate the factorial or a real non-integer numbers? Do you want to get into the Gamma function?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean $\,n^\epsilon\;\;,\;\;\log^bn\,$? And what do you mean "compare"?

For example, we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\epsilon}{\log^bn}=\infty$$

so $\,n^\epsilon>\log^bn\,$ for all $\,n>N\,$ , for some $\,N\in\Bbb N\,$ , and for all $\,\epsilon>0\,,\,b>1\,$...is this what you're looking for?